# Not able to run(schedule) oozie example map reduce job || java.net.ConnectException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am using Hadoop 2.6.0 and oozie 5.2.0 version.
Trying to run example Map reduce job in oozie but getting below error.

```
hadoop1@ip-172-31-84-37:/usr/local/oozie-5.2.0/examples/target/examples/apps/map-reduce$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/oozie/oozie-5.2.0/embedded-oozie-server/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/oozie/oozie-5.2.0/embedded-oozie-server/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/oozie/oozie-5.2.0/libext/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Error: E0307 : E0307: Runtime error [Could not check whether file [hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hadoop1/examples/apps/map-reduce/workflow.xml] exists on HDFS. Error message: Call From ip-172-31-84-37/172.31.84.37 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused]
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/602CZ.png)
Not sure if I have to change any configurations. I tried giving public dns in job.properties file instead of localhost but still got the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Docker or AWS, by chance? If you are in AWS, then you should really use EMR instead, which would be preconfigured to use Oozie (although Airflow would be preferred)

Comment: I am using AWS. Would check that option. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`Call From ip-172-31-84-37/172.31.84.37 to localhost:8020` seems to say that your Oozie server (on localhost) is not running HDFS on port 8020. Use the wiki page in the error to debug your network setup...

Assuming you have an external HDFS address, then `fs.defaultFS` in `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml` needs updated with the correct address.

Comment: i have my HDFS address in fs.defaultFS in $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml

Comment: And it is a different value than `hdfs://localhost:8020`? If so, your error message would read differently